# Optimization of relatively basic JOIN and GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have a relatively basic query that fetches the most recent messages per conversation:

```
SELECT `message`.`conversation_id`, MAX(`message`.`add_time`) AS `max_add_time`
FROM `message` 
LEFT JOIN `conversation` ON `message`.`conversation_id` = `conversation`.`id` 
WHERE ((`conversation`.`receiver_user_id` = 1 AND `conversation`.`status` != -2)
OR (`conversation`.`sender_user_id` = 1 AND `conversation`.`status` != -1))
GROUP BY `conversation_id` 
ORDER BY `max_add_time` DESC
LIMIT 12
```

The `message` table contains more than 911000 records, the `conversation` table contains around 680000. The execution time for this query, varies between 4 and 10 seconds, depending on the load on the server. Which is far too long.

Below is a screenshot of the `EXPLAIN` result:

[image]

The cause is apparently the `MAX` and/or the `GROUP BY`, because the following similar query only takes 10ms:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `message` 
LEFT JOIN `conversation` ON `message`.`conversation_id` = `conversation`.`id` 
WHERE (`message`.`status`=0) 
AND (`message`.`user_id` <> 1) 
AND ((`conversation`.`sender_user_id` = 1 OR `conversation`.`receiver_user_id` = 1))
```

The corresponding `EXPLAIN` result:

[image]

I have tried adding different indices to both tables without any improvement, for example: `conv_msg_idx(add_time, conversation_id)` on `message` which seems to be used according to the first `EXPLAIN` result, however the query still takes around 10 seconds to execute.

Any help improving the indices or query to get the execution time down would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have changed the query to use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT `message`.`conversation_id`, MAX(`message`.`add_time`) AS `max_add_time`
FROM `message` 
INNER JOIN `conversation` ON `message`.`conversation_id` = `conversation`.`id` 
WHERE ((`conversation`.`receiver_user_id` = 1 AND `conversation`.`status` != -2)
OR (`conversation`.`sender_user_id` = 1 AND `conversation`.`status` != -1))
GROUP BY `conversation_id` 
ORDER BY `max_add_time` DESC
LIMIT 12
```

But the execution time is still ~ 6 seconds.

Comment: Remark: You write `OUTER JOIN`, but you actually get the result on an `INNER JOIN` (due to the WHERE-condition on `conversation`) , MySQL used to quite bad on noticing that. If your result is what you actually want remove the `LEFT`.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` queries usually are a lot faster.

Comment: I would denormalise and store the latest message timestamp or id (if the message id is auto increment) in the conversation table and keep it updated via trigger.

Comment: @dnoeth @EmileEichenberger thanks for the suggestions, I have changed the join type to `INNER JOIN`, the improvement is minimal

Comment: @Shadow I though about this too, and will probably use that as a solution if this query does not turn out to be improvable. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `message`.`conversation_id`, MAX(`message`.`add_time`) AS `max_add_time`
FROM `message` 
INNER JOIN `conversation` ON `message`.`conversation_id` = `conversation`.`id` 
WHERE ((`conversation`.`receiver_user_id` = 1 AND `conversation`.`status` != -2)
OR (`conversation`.`sender_user_id` = 1 AND `conversation`.`status` != -1))
GROUP BY `conversation_id` 
ORDER BY `max_add_time` DESC
LIMIT 12
```

You can try with `INNER JOIN`, if your logic not get affect using it.

Comment: I have tried `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` and the improvement is barely noticeable

Comment: Then obviously go with `INNER JOIN` even though minor effect is there.

Answer (score 0):

You should create Multiple-Column Index on the columns which are in your WHERE clause and which you want to SELECT (except conversation_id). ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html))
conversation_id should be an index in both table.

Comment: Thisanswer would be a lot more useful if you actually made a suggestion as to how those indexes should look like. Bear in mind, that group by and join also needs index and mysql can only use a single index under most cirmstances per table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid 'Or' in Sql query this will make the fetching slow. Instead use union or any other methods.

SELECT message.conversation_id, MAX(message.add_time) AS max_add_time FROM message INNER JOIN conversation ON message.conversation_id = conversation.id WHERE (conversation.sender_user_id = 1 AND conversation.status != -1)) GROUP BY conversation_id 
union

SELECT message.conversation_id, MAX(message.add_time) AS max_add_time FROM message INNER JOIN conversation ON message.conversation_id = conversation.id WHERE ((conversation.receiver_user_id = 1 AND conversation.status != -2) ) GROUP BY conversation_id ORDER BY max_add_time DESC LIMIT 12

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate, but even removing the entire `WHERE` clause doesn't really help the execution time, in this case it's the `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` thats making the query slow.

Comment: Did u try to run without 'or' in the same query that you have posted.

Comment: Yes, I have tried without the OR, the WHERE clause looked like this: `... WHERE conversation.sender_user_id = 1 GROUP BY conversation_id ...`. -
 almost no difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify this query by avoiding max() use

```
   select * from(
select row_number() over(partition by conversation_id  order by add_time desc)p1
                )t1  where t1.p1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on a single table `message`, have two tables:  One for `message`, as you have, plus another `thread` that keeps the status of the thread of messages.

Yes, that requires a little more work when adding a new message -- update a column or two in `thread`.

But it eliminates the `GROUP BY` and `MAX` that are causing grief in this query.

While doing this split, see if some other columns would be better off in the new table.